# (Optionally) hide questions where I made the most recent change

Tags: feature-request

I spend a fair bit of time walking through the "unanswered" section on SF, and would love to be able to hide all questions where I was the last person to update, to better see questions that might still need responses / voting.

Comment: Sounds like a job for Greasemonkey!

Comment: How is the client side (Greasemonkey) going to know what other users have done on a question?